# Can't delete urandom file at /dev (OS Monterey)

Tags: macos, terminal, command, finder

I created a urandom file 20GB size following this tutorial [Installing Xcode with “not enough disk space available”](https://medium.com/geekculture/installing-xcode-with-not-enough-disk-space-available-b96c8f17115b) trying to install XCode on my mac. After creating a urandom file I can't delete it using "rm urandom" on Terminal and /dev folder does not appear in Finder.

I can see other "hidden" folders such as bin, cores, etc, but not dev.

My laptop is mac book pro with macOS Monterey v 12.0.1

Answer (score 1):

`urandom` is a character device (see the `crw-rw-rw-` if you run `ls -l /dev/urandom`).

If you followed the article you have created a file named `temp_20GB_file`, this is the one you have to delete.